# 5v/2.1A Power Bank batteries powering LED strip dropping output at 260mA

Tags: arduino, power, batteries, voltage-regulator, ws2811

I am having an issue with powering a 30 x ws2812 RGB LED strip with a 5v/2.1A "power bank" battery.  The strip is controlled by an Arduino Pro Mini(-ish) clone (3.3v @ 16 MHz) (http://www.anarduino.com/mini/).  This Arduino clone does not have an on-board 3.3v regulator.  So, I am using an AMS1117-3.3 regulator module. (https://www.openimpulse.com/blog/products-page/product-category/ams1117-3-3v-voltage-regulator-module/.)  The unregulated 5v also supplies the LED strip.

When I use the power bank battery, The Arduino starts up,  But, when the LEDs come on to any significant brightness the regulated output drops to about 2.2v, and the Arduino stops.  I don't see this issue when I use a 5v/4A wall wart supply.  Note that with the wall wart, I am only drawing about 750mA.  When I use the battery, the Arduino is pulling about 260 mA--no where close the advertised 2.1A.  I have tried two different power bank batteries from different manufacturers with the same result.

One thought I had was that this was an inrush current issue--even though the capacitive load shouldn't really be that high.  Note that each LED presents about 15pF.  But, to test this, I modified the Arduino code to slowly turn on the LEDs--one at a time over the course of a few seconds.  Again the system halted (slower) at 260 mA.  If I only turn on about 10 LEDs, it works fine with the power bank battery.

So, this obviously appears to be a power/load issue.  But, I am still wondering, under what circumstances, will these power bank batteries provide anything close to 2.1A of output?  My understanding of these power bank batteries is they are basically Li batteries (3.7v) with a buck/boost regulator to bring them up to 5v.  Is there some weird load interaction between the power bank regulator and the AMS1117-3.3 that is causing the output voltage to drop?  Thoughts?  Ideas?

Comment: You've provided links for the Arduino and the regulator, but it's the battery which seems to be the problem. So link, already.

Comment: Plus, add some idea of how things are wired up, currently. We could guess (perhaps with some chance at being right.) But that's not our job. Even stating the obvious, helps.

Comment: How is your arduino using 750 mA with one supply but only 250 mA with a different one? Do you mean the current drops because of the voltage droop? And did you try a different style power bank? You may have tried two from a different manufacturer but they are probably still the super cheap bar types. They arn't actually 2.1A out, they are likely <1 Amp and 2100 mAh.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, here are the two power banks I tried:
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00ODNPZ5A/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01AS0D52Q/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @jonk, not sure of the best way to post an diagram attachment, so here is a description:

1.  Power source (power bank or wall wart supply) + and - connected to AMS1117-3.3 module Vin and GND and WS2812 Vcc and GND.
2.  AMS1117-3.3 Vout and GND connected to Anarduino Mini Vcc and GND.
3.  10K Resistor + 1N4001 diode connected between power source + and Andarduino D10.
4.  WS2812 Data connected to anode of 1N0001.  This provides for a Data signal from D10 (@3.3v), plus a diode drop for ~3.6v.  This is needed to satisfy the Vih 0.7Vcc requirements of the WS2812.

(Pretty simple).

Comment: @Passerby, yes.  Basically, when the voltage from the supply is dragged down, the Arduino stops.  I blink the on-board LED to see that the Arduino sketch is running.  When the voltage drops, it stops blinking (and the LED strip stops changing color).  When this happens, I am only drawing 250mA.  When I use the same setup, but with the wall wart supply, everything works fine, and I measure that I am drawing 750mA.

Comment: With regards to the quality of the batteries, I can't rule it out as a culprit.  However, these batteries were chosen for their capacity, power output, and Amazon customer rating.  I have also used these battery models (note, not the same battery instance) with my Android phone and tablet.  They work fine for those.